# Login via ssh without password, getting authorized_keys file removed after first login attempt

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

I'm trying to configure passwordless login via ssh.
I have Centos 6.5
This what I did:

- copied content of id_rsa.pub from my client machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- set permissions 700 to `~/.ssh` and 600 to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- added the following lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

> ```
> RSAAuthentication yes
> PubkeyAuthentication yes
> AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
> ```

- restarted sshd service

But still it asks a password and it deletes `.ssh/authorized_keys` from the server after first login attempt.

Could anyone please help me to solve the problem?

### sshd_config

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

#Port 22
AddressFamily inet
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
# activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#GatewayPorts no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   ForceCommand cvs server
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
UseDNS no
PrintMotd no
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/scripts/ssh_ldap_auth.sh
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole of /etc/ssh/sshd_config without comments.

Comment: @EightBitTone done

Comment: I'm guessing this is your problem `AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/scripts/ssh_ldap_auth.sh`.  That's not standard and appears to be suggesting your server is doing LDAP of some kind.  Try it without that line initially, and see if that helps.

Comment: Exactly! I've found this line: `rm -f /home/$SYSUSER/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Ok, I'll contact guys who provided me this machine... Thanks you, @EightBitTony!

Comment: Okay, popped it in as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this line as the likely culprit,

`AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/scripts/ssh_ldap_auth.sh`

It's unusual (but obviously supported).  The man page suggests it is used to 'collect the keys' before checking the authorizedkeys file, and may be interacting with the local copy or forcing password authorisations.

Given you have found this present in that script,

`rm -f /home/$SYSUSER/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I think we can be confident that's the source of the issue.